# Does Perl support for i in list syntax

Tags: perl

I can do the following using Bash:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    # Do some operations on $i
    print $i
done
```

Can I do something similar in Perl without storing the values in an array?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Or are you asking due to curiosity?

Comment: Errr... Perl or Bash?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear about that... it is clear if you read the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a lot of answers. The [Perl Best Practices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) says not to use `$_` or `foreach`, and to put `{` on the same line as the `for`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use features qw(say);

for my $i (1, 2, 3, 4) {
    say "$i";
}
```

However, this is the same thing but cleaner:

```
for my $i ( qw(1 2 3 4) ) {
    say $i;
}
```

Here I'm using `qw` which produces a list of the *words* in the parentheses. I don't need commas or even quotes:

```
for my $i ( qw(apple baker charlie delta) ) {
    say $i;
}
```

As others pointed out, in your particular example, you could have used:

```
for my $i (1..4) {
    say "$i";
}
```

But then, you could have done this in BASH or Kornshell too:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
    echo $i   #In BASH you have to use "echo". The "print" is a Kornshellism
done
```

Comment: `for my $i qw(...) { ... }` has been deprecated since Perl 5.14, and from 5.18 is a syntax error. You need some parentheses _outside_ the `qw(...)`. Like this: `for my $i (qw(...)) { ... }`.

Comment: Ah! That's where the double parentheses are needed. I thought it was needed for `(1..4)`, but Perl tidy wouldn't complain about that. Thanks.

Comment: Also the positioning of `{}` is merely a taste question, not really a *best practice*.

Comment: @m0skit0 Damian Conway's _Perl Best Practices_: _Brace and parenthesize in K&R style._ (Page 9). Most shops use Conway's book as the Bible on Perl coding style (much as a Java shop uses Checkstyle). It reduces bickering "_Should we cuddle or not cuddle braces? Let's see what Conway says..." Some of Conway's rules are just a matter of taste. However, having everyone use the same style makes maintaining programs easier, and Conway has become the standard. If you're learning Perl, you might do it Conway's way. I use to use uncuddled braces (Perl 3 way), but now have drunk the Koolade.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, didn't know since I'm not that much into Perl worl. Technically speaking, I'm not learning Perl, but actually I learn something new everyday. I'll try to follow tese best practices. Although I hate with all my heart to put { on the same line. And I'm currenly a Java dev mainly. Imagine my inner conflicts... Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @m0skit0 I thought it's the same standard in Java. Blame Kernighan and Ritchie, the _previous_ standard was what was in Pascal where you had the words _BEGIN_ and _END_ to mark blocks. K & R changed those to curly braces because they were faster to type. By the time they wrote their first C book, they started putting the opening curly brace on the same line to save a space. Other programming languages followed. If you don't like it, learn Python which does away with braces altogether. Python is the bestest, greatest most marvelous language in the whole world. Just ask any Python programmer!

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm not fond of many of the Perl standards myself. Underscore in variable names instead of CamelCasing? CamelCasing variable names has been used by programmers since the use of meaningful variable names! However, a standard is good not because it's good, but because no one can argue about it. 90% of programming is maintenance, and maintenance is easier if you can easily follow the logic of the code. Thus, I've switched from CamelCasing to underscores because __the standard__ says so.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. `for` operates on a list.

```
for my $i (1, 2, 3, 4) {
    # Do some operations on $i
    print $i
}
```

Although, with data like that, you would be better off with a range: `(1 .. 4)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, perl support that. You can write easy a list like this in Perl:

```
for (1..4) {
    print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure Perl can. Try with:

```
for (1..4)
{
    # Do some operations on $_
    print $_;   
}
```

or if you want `$i` instead of default `$_`:

```
for my $i (1..4)
{
    # Do some operations on $i
    print $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner, from the command prompt, would be:

$ perl -e 'printf "%i\n", $_ for (0..4)'

Answer (score -1):

Found it:

```
foreach (1,2,3,4)
{
    print $_;
}
```

I understand that (1,2,3,4) is still an array. But this suits my needs.

Comment: Why answer your own question when it has already been answered... :S

Comment: *I understand that (1,2,3,4) is still an array.* — It isn't an array, it is a list.

Comment: I found it in about 2 minutes and started writing the answer. Seems like things happened in parallel. Sorry about that.

Comment: See this Post for a very good explanation of the differences from Lists and Arrays in Perl: http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl

Comment: And you could also write `foreach (1..4)` which is even more elegant.

Comment: @BorisDäppen or `for (1..4)` for world-class elegancy.

Comment: `perl -E 'say for 1..4'` even tops that :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can do such things. E.g. with a while loop:

```
use feature qw( say );

my $arg = ''; 
while ($arg = shift @ARGV) {
    say $arg;
}
```

This gives:

```
$ perl tmp.pl arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

You can do this also with reading files or other types of operations. Also see this new Blogpost which talks about a module that allows also such kind of processing in a while loop: http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2013/07/a-generator-object-for-perl-5.html

Comment: Note that this modifies the array variable used as the argument to `shift`, and will also stop prematurely if the array happens to have a false value in it.

Comment: I brought this example to show that you can do such loops without using arrays (or lists)... because I wasn't sure what he meant by saying "without storing the values in an array"... but you are right with what you are saying.